# Replicate sample from population using distributions

Tags: simulation, population

I would like to replicate a sample from a population. For this, the distribution (PDF) of $n$ characteristics are calculated. Then I just draw at random from each PDF, and put it as part of the new sample.

**How this process is called (if it has a name)?**

Comment: Depending on how the PDF is calculated, how many samples are obtained, and what is meant by "take note," this process is an integral part of many procedures, including parametric bootstrapping, multiple imputation, and Monte-Carlo simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to generate new samples based on a PDF determined from your data. Such a process is known as oversampling and there exists a paper which does exactly this. Check it out: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6252384

Comment: I'm reading the paper. If I understand, it is one PDF calculated for all the feature space?

Comment: Because it is not just one PDF, it could be $n$ features; so, I think, there will be also $n$ PDFs for each feature.